# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, spring-mvc, transactions

I've got this error accessing a servlet I've declared:

> ```
> org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy
> - no Session at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:167)
> at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
> at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:190)
> at com.confloorapp.domain.Floor_$$_javassist_0.setNumberOfEvents(Floor_$$_javassist_0.java)
> at com.ifloor.services.endpoint.UpdateFloorEventServlet.doGet(UpdateFloorEventServlet.java:59)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
> at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
> at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
> at net.stax.appserver.webapp.RequestMonitorValve.invoke(RequestMonitorValve.java:35)
> at net.stax.appserver.admin.StaxApplicationQueryValve.invoke(StaxApplicationQueryValve.java:49)
> at net.stax.appserver.webapp.RequestSetupValve.invoke(RequestSetupValve.java:31)
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:652)
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> ```

When getting the service directly from a Servlet:

```
public class UpdateFloorEventServlet extends HttpServlet {

@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(getServletContext());

    try {
        FloorService floorService = (FloorService)context.getBean("floorService");
        Floor floor = (Floor) floorService.findById (floorId);
        ...
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
@Service("floorService")
public class FloorServiceImpl implements FloorService {
  ...
}
```

Thanks

I see that the problem is not related to the controller, its related when I set a property:

```
 floor.setNumberOfEvents    ((Long)numOfEvents);

@Entity
@Table(name="T_FLOOR")
public class Floor  {

@Id
@Column(name = "FLOOR_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Integer id;
@Column(name = "FLOOR_KEY")
private String floorKey;
@Column(name = "NUMBER_OF_EVENTS")
private Long numberOfEvents;

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Long getNumberOfEvents() {
    return numberOfEvents;
}
public void setNumberOfEvents(Long numberOfEvents) {
    this.numberOfEvents = numberOfEvents;
}
public String getFloorKey() {
    return floorKey;
}
public void setFloorKey(String floorKey) {
    this.floorKey = floorKey;
}   
}
```

MySQL

```
  CREATE TABLE `T_FLOOR` (
  `FLOOR_ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FLOOR_KEY` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FLOOR_DESC` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCATION_ID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NUMBER_OF_EVENTS` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_EVENT` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LAST_UPDATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `LATITUDE` float DEFAULT NULL,
  `LONGITUDE` float DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`FLOOR_ID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `FLOOR_ID_UNIQUE` (`FLOOR_ID`),
   KEY `FK_floor_location` (`LOCATION_ID`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_door_location` FOREIGN KEY (`LOCATION_ID`) REFERENCES `T_LOCATION` (`LOCATION_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: What is in the line 59 of `UpdateFloorEventServlet`?

Comment: More importantly why have you mashed up your controller and service layers? They should be kept totally separate. You shouldn't need to be extending HttpServlet, you should be making a controller class and using the MVC annotation @Controller. You are smashing the entire point of Spring's IoC with this class.

Comment: If you are determined to do this however, have you correctly set up your transaction manager? What Hibernate is saying is that it has no Transactional session so it can't set the collection that you are trying to set. It would help if we could see the object that you are trying to modify in the service.

Comment: You'll need to post the Spring configuration you are using

Comment: I see that the problem is nothing related to the controller, Its when I set the object floor.setNumberOfEvents((Long)numOfEvents);